# DNS issues with my TP-Link router

Tags: router, dns, internet-connection, adsl

I own a TP-Link TD-W8101G router that also includes an ADSL modem function.

Lately I've been seeing problems with my Internet connection. When I have my torrent application open (uTorrent), most DNS requests fail.

As soon as I shutdown uTorrent, everything comes back to normal. Here are some possible causes:

1. Provider's DNS Server problem: I changed to Google's DNS and get the same problem
2. Router limitations: searched for a firmware upgrade (there isn't one) and searched for an open source firmware (not compatible)
3. The Internet provider is "limiting" my DNS requests

Does anyone have any ideas on the matter? How could I test the third possible cause above?

Comment: When you changed DNS to Google, where did you change it, in the client's OS, or in your router?  Have you gone over the uTorrent "Help my DNS stopped working" forum thread? (here: http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=73560&p=1)